# Simple JQuery nested list traversing question

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem that I'm sure is very simple, yet I have spent hours trying to get it to work to no avail.

I am trying to display a nested list whenever a parent list item is clicked.

This is the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#menu ul ul" ).hide();


$("#menu ul li").click(function() {
$(this).next().toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a id="database" href="#">Database</a></li>

<ul>
<li><a href="#">view database</a></li>
<li><a href="#">edit database</a></li>
</ul>

<li><a id="production" href="#">Production</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">add order</a></li>
<li><a href="#">plan orders</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now When I click the fisrt ul li's the correct nested list toggles, however when I click the nested li's they too toggle. It must be something to do with the way I am selecting the first nested list...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's get some valid markup, the `<ul>` elements can't be direct children of another `<ul>`, they should be inside a `<li>`, like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="database" href="#">Database</a>            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">view database</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">edit database</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="production" href="#">Production</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">add order</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">plan orders</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After that, you just need to stop the `click` event from bubbling up to the parent `<li>`, like this:

```
$("#menu ul li").click(function(e) {
  $(this).children("ul").toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZeNZk/).

Comment: Many thanks! I was suspicious about my list mark-up, thanks for pointing that out. Also, thanks for pointing me towards JSFIDDLE, looks very useful.